# How does a TLB differ from a Hash table?

Tags: hashtable, tlb

I'm a noob, sorry to say, I understand both what a hash table is and what a translation lookaside buffer (TLB) is but it seems like they work on similar principals. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hardware vs. software?

Answer (score 0):

A hash table uses a hash function that maps a certain space of original values to a smaller space of resulting values. The idea is that if the original space normally not used completely, one would better use the mapped space e.g. for table lookup. Since in this mapping, more than one original value is mapped to the same resulting value, conflicts can arise that require conflict resolution, which is no problem.
A TLB, on the other hand, is used to map a large virtual memory space to a small physical memory space. To do so, it caches virtual addresses, i.e. it maps a virtual address to a physical address. There are many ways to do this. The most simple (for explanation) is a direct mapped cache. It uses the upper part of the virtual address as the address of the cache memory. Stored there are the lower part of the virtual address together with the corresponding physical address. One could thus consider this as a hash table with a hash function that maps all virtual addresses that have the same upper bits to the same cache address. However, conflicts are here (in the direct mapped cache) resolved by replacing an old entry by a new entry. If the cache organization is more complex, i.e. as a multi-way associative cache, conflicts are handled by distributing new entries among the available associative storage locations.
So, you are right, there is no essential difference between hash tables and TLBs.

Comment: @CMendel: Did this answer your question? If so, please accept the answer so that it is marked as closed. If not, what is missing?